# Python lxml html builder

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

hey guys i want to make a html in python. I read a xml with python requests. And i counted the elements of an attribute.

```
count = len(nodeData.xpath("//user[@condition='good']"))
print (count)`
```

like this.

but now i want to get a table in which the number of the count stays.

```
nodeRow = html.TR(html.TD(count , style="background-color:#FF0000")
nodeTable.append(nodeRow)

print etree.tostring(nodeTable)
with open("out3.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(nodeTable))
```

But that doesn't work. The error is

> TypeError: bad argument type: int(2746)

Comment: Does that error come with a line number? (Hint: **yes**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error-code is pretty clear - you can't put strings into the text-content of an Element. As you have an int, Python balks. Convert it to a string first:

```
nodeRow = html.TR(html.TD(str(count) , style="background-color:#FF0000")
```

You should consider using a template library though, it will make doing this much easier, as it takes care of these little obstacles, and allows a more natural writing of longer HTML snippets.

Comment: @123bodyuilding: then accept this answer. You may want to read the introductory [tour] some time as well (yes, we can tell you did not). Maybe a glance through the [help] would be good too.